# cannot ping from a container pod in one service to another service - grpc client cannot connect to grpc server

Tags: ssl, service, certificate, kubernetes, grpc

I am getting the below error when my gRPC client is running in one pod/container and trying to invoke another service running in another pod/container exposed via a kubernetes service

> Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in
>   TransientFailure Error Code: 14

I have created a TLS certificate using cfssl and saved it as a secret and am able to read the certificates.

The certificate is self signed with below details:

```
Common Name: *.default.svc.cluster.local
Subject Alternative Names: *, localhost, login, order, login.default, order.default, login.default.svc.cluster.local, order.default.svc.cluster.local, IP Address:127.0.0.1
Organization: None
Organization Unit: api
Locality: Cupertino
State: California
Country: US
Valid From: January 3, 2018
Valid To: January 3, 2019
Issuer: *.default.svc.cluster.local, None
Serial Number: 16ab6a399473af3c095842eccdf7aaeaecaeb368
```

My gRPC client is running on `login.default.svc.cluster.local` and is showing the above failure. I am not sure if the certificates imported have an issue with domains listed or with common name.

The same certificates do run outside kubernetes on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with booting my grpc server with only port ":80" rather than "localhost:80" and was also able to connect with certificate or with insecure mode